# on input convert to UTF-16 jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating a jQuery plugin which will convert each character in an `input[type='text']` and output in the console.

This is what I have done so far. The problem that I am having is that it will only calculate the UTF-16 code for the first character even though there are more than one character.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <input type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery Plugin

```
this.on("input", function() {
  for (i = 0; i < $(this).length; i++) {
    console.log($(this).val().charCodeAt(0));
  }
});
```

**Current Output**

If I enter `a` and `b` the console will only display `97`

**Expected Output**

`97`
`98`

How can I make it append the value of each character? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Er... [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) does not use ASCII at all. It returns the UTF-16 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$(this)` is a jQuery object, `$(this).length` is number of matching elements, thus will always be 1.

You want something like `$(this).val().length` and, of course, you should probably store it in a variable rather than creating a new jQuery object on every iteration:

```
// Untested code
this.on("input", function() {
  var text = $(this).val();
  var length = text.length;
  for (i = 0; i < length ; i++) {
    console.log(text.charCodeAt(i));
  }
});
```

Comment: That's perfect!! Thank you very much :) Sorry for the misunderstanding of UTF-16 and ASCII. Thanks again